# SSL certificate in local IIS

Tags: ssl, iis

**Hello Everyone**

Is it possible to upload SSL certificate in (local) IIS ?
if so , please provide me for the steps

if it is not possible, how can I make it  runs in a global

sorry for the stupids questions but I am really newb in IIS

Comment: What do you mean by "uploading SSL certificate in (local) IIS"? That's not a common way to use certificates, so you must reveal more details.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know more details about “upload SSL certificate in IIS”. In my opinion, IIS can create a self-signed certificate by using the Server certificate tool. 
[image]
Also, it supports that importing a PFX file to the certificate store.
[image]
We can also import it to the local machine certificates store by clicking the certificate file to install it so that every user account in the machine can refer to the certificate when binding a certificate to a port.
[image]
Finally, a certificate is commonly used to bind to a port so that secure the communication. We could refer to this link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.